# Is Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro supported by ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore, xiaomi

I was trying to google it but most results was about Redmi K20 Pro. I know that they are very similiar but there are small differences between them and I want to be sure if I can run ARCore on Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro before I buy it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.xiaomitoday.com/xiaomi-mi-9t-and-mi-9t-pro-are-already-compatible-with-googles-arcore/

Apparently yes, the Xiaomi Mi 9T (and 9T Pro) are compatible with Google ARCore.